# How can I overlay images over one another in Java?

Tags: java, awt, overlay, drawimage

So I have been posting all over and have yet to get a solid answer:

I have created an image resizing class, with a crop method. The cropping works great. The issue that I am having is the background color that I specify in the `drawImage` function of `Graphics` is not working correctly. It defaults to black as the background regardless of what I supply (in this case `Color.WHITE`).

Also, the overlaying image or top most image (comes from a file) is being inverted (I think it is) or otherwise discolored. Just so you can conceptualize this a little bit better, I am taking a jpeg and overlaying it on top of a new `BufferedImage`, the new buffered image's background is not being set. Here is the code below that I am working with:

```
public void Crop(int Height, int Width, int SourceX, int SourceY) throws Exception {
    //output height and width
    int OutputWidth = this.OutputImage.getWidth();
    int OutputHeight = this.OutputImage.getHeight();

    //create output streams
    ByteArrayOutputStream MyByteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    MemoryCacheImageOutputStream MyMemoryCacheImageOutputStream = new MemoryCacheImageOutputStream(MyByteArrayOutputStream);

    //Create a new  BufferedImage
    BufferedImage NewImage = new BufferedImage(Width, Height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics MyGraphics = NewImage.createGraphics();

    MyGraphics.drawImage(this.OutputImage, -SourceX, -SourceY, OutputWidth, OutputHeight, Color.WHITE, null);

    // Get Writer and set compression
    Iterator MyIterator = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("png");
    if (MyIterator.hasNext()) {
        //get image writer
        ImageWriter MyImageWriter = (ImageWriter)MyIterator.next();

        //get params
        ImageWriteParam MyImageWriteParam = MyImageWriter.getDefaultWriteParam();

        //set outputstream
        MyImageWriter.setOutput(MyMemoryCacheImageOutputStream);

        //create new ioimage
        IIOImage MyIIOImage = new IIOImage(NewImage, null, null);

        //write new image
        MyImageWriter.write(null, MyIIOImage, MyImageWriteParam);
    }

    //convert output stream back to inputstream
    ByteArrayInputStream MyByteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(MyByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());
    MemoryCacheImageInputStream MyMemoryCacheImageInputStream = new MemoryCacheImageInputStream(MyByteArrayInputStream);

    //resassign as a buffered image
    this.OutputImage = ImageIO.read(MyMemoryCacheImageInputStream);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you isolate whether it's the Graphics methods or the ImageIO methods that are mangling your image?  It looks like you could test this by short-circuiting the entire ImageIO process and simply assigning

```
this.OutputImage = NewImage;
```

For that matter, I assume there's something gained by the ImageIO operations?  As the sample is written, it appears to be (ideally) a no-op.

Also, you don't dispose your Graphics2D before you begin the ImageIO process.  It often doesn't make a difference, but you don't want to assume that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, much appreciated

As far as isolating, its weird, i removed all the over lay stuff and just created a new buffered image and setBackgroundColor and assigned to  this.OutputImage and i still get a black background. Also, just to clearify, I am using Graphics - not Graphics2D.

Comment: What's the new code look like?  Setting the background color alone won't change the image--it's only used in the clear operations (clearRect, possibly Graphics2D composites?).

Answer (score 1):

On the overlay color distortion problem, make sure your graphics context is in paint mode and not xor mode.  (Graphics.setPaintMode()).  Otherwise the color bits are XOR'd together.

Comment: Here is the solution:

    //set background
    MyGraphics.setBackground(Color.decode(this.BackgroundColor));
    
    //clear rect
    MyGraphics.clearRect(0, 0, Width, Height);

Thanks for all your help !